# Save private data to public location

Tags: java, android

I am trying to open my PDF file with PDF Reader, I am searching more on how can i done this, a lot of answer found but every answer tells that save that file to "SD Card".

Saving file to SD Card is good idea but the problem is if user not installed SD Card in his phone. At present time many phone have large inbuilt memory for example: Samsung galaxy S3, HTC One V, Samsung Galaxy Note, Sony Xperia S and many phone.

**So my Question is**: These phones already have a large inbuilt memory, so user not need to add SD Card with it (it depends on user). In this case **which location is accessible to other applications** like public location (SD Card).

When I searching for my problem i found this [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) that tell about location for saving application data provided by Android Platform.

Android Platform provides these options to save app data:

1. Shared Preferences
2. Internal Storage
3. External Storage
4. SQLite Databases
5. Network Connection

Android provides a way to expose private data to other applications — with a content provider

I read about content provider but i didn't understand how it works.

If any tutorial show how it works please provide that tutorial link or if this can done in other way please tell me how.

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not sure what you are asking - do you mean your app is a PDF reader and you are wondering how to access a PDF?

Comment: @brianestey no my app is a simple app. it contains a PDF file in assets folder and i want to open that file with PDF Reader which is already installed on my android phone.

Comment: @brianestey and if i am saving pdf file to SD Card and then open it it opens easily but if i Unmount my sd card and then open it shows error "File path not valid". Now i want to save my file on that location which was accessible by other application even when i Unmount sd card.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) it appears that the only real option you have to keep your PDF in a public storage is to store it in external storage.  You could always get your app to check if external storage is available and then, if so, use it to share your PDF.

Another approach that you could try (I haven't tried this, just thought of it now) is to write the PDF to a Temp file and then share that temp File's location.

[File.createTempFile()](http://developer.android.com/reference/java/io/File.html#createTempFile(java.lang.String,java.lang.String)) will create a temporary file.  You could experiment to see where that temp file is saved and then if that location is accessible by other apps.

Comment: I don't know, if it works, but i really like the concept of the last one!+1

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following technology for saving, instead of SDCard..

1. Shared Preferences
   Ex:--SharedPreferences demo_sp = getApplicationContext()
               .getSharedPreferences("demo", MODE_PRIVATE);
       String dem= demo_sp.getString("DEMO", "demo");
2. Internal Storage
3. SQLite database, once you store anything in sqlite, it will create on .db file in your phone, u can access that

Answer (score 0):

In my app I use the sdCard only if available and the phone memory otherwise.

For phone Memory you can get a file object like so:

```
File file=new File(context.getFilesDir(), FILENAME);
```

where of course context is a Context object. You can then use this file like a regular Java file with read/write operations.

For Sd Card storage you must first declare this in you manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

You should check if external storage is available:

```
public static boolean hasSdCard(){
    return android.os.Environment.getExternalStorageState().equals(android.os.Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED);
}
```

Then you can get a file object

```
File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + DIRECTORY + FILENAME);
```